# help me to convert to polar coordinates

Tags: integration

Convert the integral below to polar coordinates and evaluate the integral.

[image]

i really tired hard to understand it but i still getting wrong answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plot region, put x=$rcos(\theta$) and y=$rsin(\theta)$
Limits of r are 0 to 5, since circle is centered at (0,0) ray of r starts at origin and goes upto circumference
u get 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^5r^3cos(\theta)sin(\theta)drd\theta$$

Comment: r bound are 0 to 5, sir

Comment: yeah that is the right answer thanks!

Comment: For clarification, why don't we have to account for the lower bound $y$ of the $dx$ integral?

Comment: if u draw the region, ur doubt will go away